# My checkbox is disabled when I exit the screen in pyqt5 python

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt5, pyside6

I have a form that has several buttons, each of which shows a list of checkboxes with a click.Now my problem with checkboxes is that when I activate them and go back to the next form, the checkboxes seem to be inactive.

When I click:
FORM ETHERNET
[image]

When I go to another form:
FORM RIP
[image]

When I return to the first form
FORM ETHERNET

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.